# How to give permission to some user which allow only view one instance by one time?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, user-permissions

I always want allow to check for all users view one instance by one time.

But another function like get(list)\post\patch\update\delete only for user which have got general perm for this actions.

```
class IsCardAccess(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        has_perm = False
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.user.has_perm_extended(PERM_CARD_ACCESS):
                has_perm = True
            elif request.user.has_perm_extended(PERM_CARD_SUPER_ACCESS):
                has_perm = True

        return has_perm
```

In this way user without PERM_CARD_ACCESS and PERM_CARD_SUPER_ACCESS can't do anything, but when PERM_CARD_ACCESS user can do all of this actions (get\post\patch\update\delete).

I don't understand what I need to do.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this question, but now I can write my answer.

I did this:

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    has_perm = False

    if not request.user or not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return has_perm

    if request.user.has_perm_extended(PERM_CARDS_ACCESS) or \
            request.user.has_perm_extended(PERM_CARDS_SUPER_ACCESS):
        has_perm = True
    elif request.user.has_perm_extended(PERM_VIEW_CARD_ACCESS):
        # user with this perm has got limited access to check card-info
        if hasattr(view, 'action'):
            resolve_url = resolve(request.path).url_name
            if view.action == 'retrieve' and resolve_url == "cards-card-detail":
                has_perm = True
            if view.action == 'list' and resolve_url == "cards-operations-list":
                has_perm = True

    return has_perm
```